# Eye tracking mouse cursor for Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, mouse, cursor

Is there any software to control mouse cursor using eye or finger via web camera in ubuntu? Windows has a software called [Camera Mouse](http://www.cameramouse.org/), that can control your cursor by tracking your eye or finger position. I want something like this for ubuntu.

Comment: Answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34493/72456 or you can run Camera Mouse itself into WINE.

Answer (score 7):

You can add a ppa for eviacam. It uses "head movements".

You can add the ppa and install eviacam using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cesar-crea-si/eviacam
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eviacam
```

[Click here for more info.](http://eviacam.sourceforge.net/#downloads)

---

**On 18.04**, eviacam is available through the Universe repository, however, it fails with a GTK error.

To work around this issue, manually download the [19.10 version of eviacam](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/eviacam/download) and use that instead.

I used `gdebi` to install and resolve dependencies like in the following example:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/eviacam/eviacam_2.1.3-4.1_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi eviacam_2.1.3-4.1_amd64.deb
```

---

**On 19.10 and newer**, you can install from the Universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install eviacam
```

Comment: I had a chance to try out Camera Mouse the other day and in my opinion, eviacam is better. Camera Mouse is jittery and if you adjust the "smoothness" it just adds latency. Eviacam is smooth and accurate immediately.

Comment: Note that this package is available in stock Ubuntu packages [since 16.04 (Xenial)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/x11/eviacam), no more need to add the PPA.

Comment: Oh, it's broken on 18.04, see [this thread](https://github.com/cmauri/eviacam/issues/14). Need to do some compilation from source, supposedly like [done here](https://github.com/Cat5TV/eviacam/blob/master/install.sh).

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks. Have you tried installing the 19.10 version instead? After installing the 19.10 version, you would need to uninstall the compiled version or explicitly call the 19.10 version by using the full path: `/usr/bin/eviacamloader` or `/usr/bin/eviacam`

Comment: No I didn't try on 19.10 since I don't have it installed anywhere.

Comment: @Ruslan I installed the [19.10 version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/eviacam/download) on 18.04 and I don't get the GTK error.

Comment: OK, it doesn't crash, but does it work though? At least I've checked that when I compiled from source eviacam and wxwidgets (GTK-3-enabled) as in the script I linked to above, on 18.04, it worked fine (i.e. moved the cursor according to head motion). That's the only configuration where it worked.

Comment: @Ruslan Yeah it works. I used "enable eviacam" listed in my installed applications and used my face to move the mouse around.